# How can I remove repetition in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm just calling a function `highlightInput(this)` which is just changing colors for selected input. I think there might be a better way to avoid repetition. Any ideas?

HTML file

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="your_name">Your name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name" onfocus="highlightInput(this);">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"onfocus="highlightInput(this);">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Event title:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title"onfocus="highlightInput(this);">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="location">Event location:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="location"onfocus="highlightInput(this);">
</div>
```

---

How highlightInput looks like:

```
var Color = {
    inputColor:function (color, self){
        $(self).css('backgroundColor', color);
    }
}

function highlightInput(self){
    Color.inputColor('lightyellow', self);
    $(self).blur(function(){
        Color.inputColor('white', self);
    });
}
```

Comment: What is version of jQuery you're using?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use JavaScript/jQuery, when it can be implemented better with CSS?

Comment: version: 1.12.4 && No specific reason.. Just I don't have enough knowledge on CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the jQuery and do it with CSS.

```css
input.form-control:focus {
 background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery selector to addEventListener.

Add the following to the `<head>` tag.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

JavaScript

```
$('input.form-control').focus(function(e){
   highlightInput(this);
});
```

Comment: You should include the `<script>` necessary to use jQuery.  I assume OP has no idea what jQuery is. anyways +1

Comment: @CalebGoodman It's tagged with jQuery. Also, OP's code contains jQuery, doesn't it? So it's safe to assume that he knows about it.

Comment: Ignore my ignorance xD

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input.form-control').blur(function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
});

$('input.form-control').focus(function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'lightyellow';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="your_name">Your name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="your_name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="title">Event title:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="location">Event location:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="location">
</div>
```